# Google Drive File Sync

Tags: sync, smb

I have google drive file sync running on a windows computer (PC#1) in my home network. The files are set to be available online-only (in the cloud). Drive file synce creates a virtual drive for this. I enabled this drive for SMB share.

Now from another PC i can map a network drive to that PC#1 Share drive. I can play the video files as well. But if i try to rename files/folders or move files i get an error. I think its just a timeout since PC#1 is connecting to cloud to make the change and PC#2 is having to wait longer if that makes sense.

Could not find this item
This is no longer located in \192.168.1.107\g\My Drive\vids. Verify the item's location and try again.

Comment: Are they symlinks or virtual files of some sort? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Virtual files i guess. not sure if you use Dropbox or google drive but it creates files and folders that aren't really stored on local disk but are in cloud. If you double click the file it starts to download it to local temp folder/cache and opens. After a set time the file is deleted. Error is Could not find this item This is no longer located in \192.168.1.107\g\My Drive\vids. Verify the item's location and try again.

Comment: The protocol you are using to access the file over the network is incompatible with the virtual file type Google Drive uses to display the files in File Explorer on the primary computer. You'll only get the functions you want IF a protocol exists that supports those functions.